# Estou querendo passar alguns dados no $request de forma que faça igual quando envia algo pelo formulário

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

```
$data = $request->all();
    $data['id_cliente']= $sistemas->id_cliente;
    $data['id_sistema']= $sistemas->id_sistema;
    $data['id_versao_atual']= $sistemas->id_versao_atual;
    $data['id_versao_anterior']= $sistemas->id_versao_anterior;
    $data['data_ult_atualizacao']=  $sistemas->data_hora_ultima_verificacao;
    $data['situacao']= 0;
    $request->request->parameters = $data;
```

só que apresenta o seguinte erro

> Exception has occurred. Error: Cannot access protected property
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$parameters

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando a função `merge()` do próprio `request`.

```
$data = [];
$data['id_cliente'] = $sistemas->id_cliente;
$data['id_sistema'] = $sistemas->id_sistema;
$data['id_versao_atual'] = $sistemas->id_versao_atual;
$data['id_versao_anterior'] = $sistemas->id_versao_anterior;
$data['data_ult_atualizacao'] =  $sistemas->data_hora_ultima_verificacao;
$data['situacao'] = 0;

$request->merge($data);
```

Comment: consegui e pra receber esse parâmetro na minha função put
protected function PUT(Request $request,$endPoint){
        
        $http = new Client(); 
        $response = $http->put( $endPoint,[$request],[
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token=$request->session()->get('token'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
    
        ]); 
        $body = $response->getBody();

    }

Comment: Legal, mas se possível testa essa outra solução, vai que ela resolve o seu problema de forma mais simples.

Comment: tu me entendeu mal, conseguir resolver com sua solução, mais to com outra duvida

Comment: para enviar e $request->() e pra receber é $request-> ... oque